# i have created react app social media platform with react-router-dom version 6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i have the isAuth finction in login page which checks weather the user isAuthenticated or not but am facing this error which am not getting it.

here is the error
Unexpected Application Error!
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons: 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM) 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

here is the components handling routing

```
import React from 'react'
import { Outlet, RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter, Navigate, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import Signin from '../pages/login/Signin'
import Signup from '../pages/signup/Signup'
import Home from '../pages/home/Home'
import Profile from '../pages/profile/Profile'
import Chatbox from '../pages/chatbox/Chatbox'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar/Navbar'
import LeftBar from '../components/LeftBar/LeftBar'
import RightBar from '../components/RightBar/RightBar'
import UserProfile from '../components/UserProfile/UserProfile'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import isAuthenticated from '../pages/login/Signin'


const ProtectedRoute =({element: Element, canActivate, redirectPath, ...rest}) => {
  const {user} = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if(canActivate && !canActivate()){
      navigate(redirectPath || '/login');

    }
  },[canActivate,navigate,redirectPath]);

  return canActivate && !canActivate() ? null : <Element {...rest}/>;
}
function Layout() {
  const Feed = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar />
        <main>
          <LeftBar />
          <div className='container'>
          
          </div>
          <RightBar />
        </main>
      </>
    );
  };

  const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: '/',
      element: <ProtectedRoute element={<Feed />} canActivate={isAuthenticated} redirectPath="/login" />,
      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          element: <Home />,
        },
        {
          path: '/profile/:id',
          element: <Profile />,
        },
        {
          path: '/chatbox/:id',
          element: <Chatbox />,
        },
      ],
    },
    // public routes
    {
      path: '/login',
      element: <Signin />,
    },
    {
      path: '/signup',
      element: <Signup />,
    },
  ]);

  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default Layout;
```

login in snippet code

```
function Signin() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("")

  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  
  
  const {user,isLoading, isError, isSuccess,message} = useSelector((state) => state.auth)
  const isAuthenticated = () => !!user;

  useEffect(() => {
   

    if(isError){
      toast.error(message);
    }
    if(isSuccess || user){
      
       navigate("/");
    
   


    }
    dispatch(reset());

  },[isError,isSuccess,message,user,navigate, dispatch])

  

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(!username){
      toast.error("Username must be provided")
    }
    if(!password){
      toast.error("Password must be provided")
    }
    const userData = {username,password}
    dispatch(login(userData))

  }

  if (isAuthenticated()){
    
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: The title of your question should reflect the problem you are trying to solve, not inform us of what you are building or have built.